# Is n!=O(2^(n lg n))?

Tags: asymptotics

By Stirling's Approximation $n! = \sqrt{2*\pi*n} * [n/e]^n * e^\alpha$

Therefore $T(n!) = O(n^n)$

$O(n^n) \neq O(2^{n \lg n})$

Is this correct? Is there another way to get this result if it is correct? Thanks.

Comment: By the way, welcome to the site!

Comment: Be careful with your use of "=".

Comment: Assuming that lg n is the base 2 logarithm, $n^n$ = $2^{n lg n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, big-O is essentially an *upper* bound so we do have
$$
n! = O(n^n)
$$
in the sense that there is a constant $c$ for which $n!\le c\;n^n$ eventually. [Note, by the way, that there's no function $T(\cdot)$ involved here.]

Now let's see if $n!=O(2^{n\log n})$. We can argue this way (assuming the log is base-2):
$$
2^{n\log n} = 2^{(\log n) n} = \left(2^{\log n}\right)^n = n^n
$$
so we can conclude that the two sets $O(n^n)$ and $O(2^{n\log n})$ are in fact equal.

Comment: Thanks. Would the same logic apply for n! = bigOmega(2^(n*lgn))? I believe it would, as n^n is the same as 2^(n * lgn) on a graph, thus it is both the upper bound (O) and lower bound (omega).

Comment: @so8857. Unfortunately, no. For example, $n^2=O(n^3)$ and $n^3=2^{3\log{n}}$ but neither of these equivalent functions serve as a *lower* bound for $n^2$.